# Does Uclibc fastbin behaving like Glibc fastbin?

Tags: malloc, heap-memory, glibc, uclibc

In Glibc there are 7 bins in fastbin from 0x20 to 0xb0 each bin hold only their size. and it's a one-way linked list.

Does the fastbin in Uclibc(0.9.33.2) is the same ? is there any difference ?

Answer (score -1):

The fastbins of Uclibc are declared in  [malloc-standard/malloc.h](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdlib/malloc-standard/malloc.h) and used in files [malloc-standard/mallinfo.c](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdlib/malloc-standard/mallinfo.c), [malloc-standard/malloc.c](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdlib/malloc-standard/malloc.c), [malloc-standard/free.c](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdlib/malloc-standard/mallinfo.c).

The `grep`  utility (when launched on source code of Uclibc) don't find them elsewhere.

A comment in `malloc.h` says:

> /*   TRIM_FASTBINS controls whether free() of a very small chunk can
> immediately lead to trimming. Setting to true (1) can reduce memory
> footprint, but will almost always slow down programs that use a lot
> of small chunks.
>
> Define this only if you are willing to give up some speed to more
> aggressively reduce system-level memory footprint when releasing
> memory in programs that use many small chunks.  You can get
> essentially the same effect by setting MXFAST to 0, but this can
> lead to even greater slowdowns in programs using many small chunks.
> TRIM_FASTBINS is an in-between compile-time option, that disables
> only those chunks bordering topmost memory from being placed in
> fastbins.
> */
> #ifndef TRIM_FASTBINS
> #define TRIM_FASTBINS  0
> #endif

So if you build the Uclibc with `TRIM_FASTBINS` it seems that the  `__do_check_remalloced_chunk` is handling them like you want.

But I am not sure, you need to compile that Uclibc library from source code and use a debugger to check that property.